# relationships in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

when we want to start a project with hibernate and a Database (MySQL or Postgresql for example) in java it's better to perform the relationships between tables in database or in hibernate or both ?
i want to know what experts do about this ?

thanx

Comment: Not sure what you mean; could you be more specific?

Comment: I guess the question is - should he define database-level foreign-key/constrains or just use what hibernate offer. If thats the case i'd suggest to stay away from database-level FKs, cause it can lead to a mess in no time. Hope that helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The whole point of hibernate, imho, is to remove yourself from the database and sql, and any dependcy to the database (and its vendor). It is literally just a store of data, and can be swapped out at a later date.

So you define your relationships (and all business logic) in the java code and let hibernate create the tables for you.

You should be aware of the [relevant hibernate setting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/438146/hibernate-question-hbm2ddl-auto-possible-values-and-what-they-do) to enable table creations, and its pitfalls.

Answer (score 0):

You can keep the relationships in your entities.

You can use the maven plugin (http://mojo.codehaus.org/maven-hibernate3/hibernate3-maven-plugin/hbm2ddl-mojo.html) to generate the relevant db schema.

This step also helps you validate the relationships that you define in the entities.